# /dev/zvol/pool/group/srv points to partition zd0p16 not volume zd0 - bug or feature?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux, udev, block-device

I am only starting to get familiar with `openzfs 2.2.0` on Linux (Ubuntu kernel 6.5) and immediately ran into something strange. A symlink I was expecting to point to a zvol block device.. was pointing to a partition on that block device. While the zfs-create manpage *seems* fairly unambiguous that `/dev/zvol/path` refers to the `path` in the ZFS namespace.

What I wanted to see:

```
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv -> ../../../zd0
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part1 -> ../../../zd0p1
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part14 -> ../../../zd0p14
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part15 -> ../../../zd0p15
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part16 -> ../../../zd0p16
```

What I did see, once (not reproducible):

```
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv -> ../../../zd0p16
```

What I saw after running `partprobe` (note: symlink name of 4th partition):

```
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv -> ../../../zd0
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part1 -> ../../../zd0p1
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part14 -> ../../../zd0p14
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part15 -> ../../../zd0p15
/dev/zvol/pool/group/srv-part3 -> ../../../zd0p16
```

Before I go on to the actual problem I was wanting to look into - how well `zfs` works for me when multiple zvol each contain *identical* partition tables (forcing Linux & udev to deal with duplicate identifiers) - I would like to understand what the precise rules for managing these symlinks are and what level of control I have to make such symlinks be provisioned the way I expect them to work.

Or maybe whatever has happened is what I *should* want, or the best I *can* get? And I just fail to understand which synchronization steps and what type of device files symlinks I should be using if I mean to *reliably* access a device file containing *partition `16` of the zfs `pool` volume I named `srv`*?

Comment: Ref: [zvol_id mapping blockdev to path](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/blob/3a8d9b848723764777ec9d772f79335726b1f6c6/udev/zvol_id.c#L77) - [Ubuntu cloud images containing those 4 partitions](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/mantic/current/mantic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img)

Comment: [openzfs issue 13294](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/13294) mentions related symptoms and makes me think this is a bug, though in that case one triggered by a (since resolved, reproducible) kernel incompatibility, not any sort of race or locking condition.